# dtreeviz TypeError in google colab

Tags: python, dtreeviz

I will visualize to tree diagram in using iris dataset and showing prediction path but repeatedly one problem showing: see this

```
TypeError: model() got an unexpected keyword argument 'X'
```

I will trying to run some code:

```
clas = DecisionTreeClassifier()
iris = load_iris()

X_train = iris.data
y_train = iris.target
clas.fit(X_train,y_train)

x = iris.data[np.random.randint(0,len(iris.data)),:]

viz = dtreeviz.model(clas,
                      X_train=X_train, y_train=y_train,
                      feature_names=iris.feature_names,
                      target_name='iris',
                      class_names=iris.target_names,
                      X=x,
                      show_path=True)
viz.view()
```

repeat to error i can't resolve it this error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-18-f6761be97782> in <cell line: 10>()
      8 x = iris.data[np.random.randint(0,len(iris.data)),:]
      9 
---> 10 viz = dtreeviz.model(clas,
     11                       X_train=X_train, y_train=y_train,
     12                       feature_names=iris.feature_names,

TypeError: model() got an unexpected keyword argument 'X'
```